# bcache performance degradation on newer version of Ubuntu kernel

Tags: ssd, bcache

I have an elasticsearch cluster which uses Azure storage with a local SSD bcache. One of the machines has poorer performance because it has cache misses while the other two machines never have cache misses. They all have a larger SSD cache than the data size, so all data should fit in the cache.

I have checked the following configuration settings on both machines.

```
/sys/block/bcache0/bcache/sequential_cutoff
/sys/block/bcache0/bcache/cache/congested_read_threshold_us
/sys/block/bcache0/bcache/cache/congested_write_threshold_us
```

The configuration is identical, only the degraded machine shows '0.0k' for sequential_cutoff instead of '0' like the others.

Turns out one of the machines' Ubuntu version has been upgraded, while two others are still at an old version.

New version: 
`Linux el5padata-0 4.4.0-112-generic #135-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 19 11:48:36 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Old version: 
`Linux el5padata-1 4.4.0-47-generic #68-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 26 19:39:52 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Does anyone know if a change between these two Ubuntu versions might lead to differences in bcache behavior? I can't seem to find a bcache changelog.